# Display Multistep Progress

Tags: views, forms

I've created a multistep form to add new customer details when they sign up. So for example, step 1 is personal details. step 2 is contact details. Step 3 in social network details.

Only the fields in step 1 are mandatory so the user can skip steps 2 and 3 and finish registration.

1. How do I display a progress bar whilst the user is using the form?
2. I was wondering if I could display a 'Profile completion' percentage in a view to show the user they've only completed x% amount of their profile?

Something like this from LinkedIn:
[image]

Thanks,
Rumman

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Profile Complete Percent](https://drupal.org/project/pcp) module..

Project page says

> Profile Complete Percent (PCP) is an add-on to the core Profile module
>   or the Profile2 module. It allows administrators to select profile
>   fields as mandatory for a user to achieve a 100% profile completeness
>   status.

[image]